# Eloquent get with query don't pass variable value

Tags: php, laravel, slim, eloquent

In My Slim App, I am using the Eloquent database. I build a model where I need to pass the course with progress according to the specific user id. In my controller I am using

```
public function course($user_id, $request, $response) 
{

    $id = $response['user_id'];
    // return json_encode($user_id);

    $course = Course::with(['progress' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', $id);
    }])->get();

    return json_encode($course);

}
```

but this have return this error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: id in line ...
```

But if I  assign

```
$course = Course::with(['progress' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', '=', 2);
        }])->get();
```

it will return the perfect result. 
why I can pass variable data which passed by URL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct.

If you want to use `$id` within the anonymous function, you need to pass it to it. It does not automatically inherit the variables from the parent scope.

```
public function course($user_id, $request, $response) 
{

    $id = $response['user_id'];
    // return json_encode($user_id);

    $course = Course::with(['progress' => function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', $id);
    }])->get();

    return json_encode($course);

}
```